# Facebook api returned comment id

Tags: php, facebook, data-structures

Whenever I submit a comment to facebook, it returns the id in this format:

```
{"id":"1178215146_2244093420005"}
```

Do you know how I can get this value out with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you pasted is [JSON](http://json.org/). Use `$arr = json_decode($val, true);`. You'll get an associative array, and you can access the value with: `$arr['id']`.

- [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) documentation